# Cannot Post to route

Tags: node.js, api

I am implementing a simple signup / login functionality in node js
But when using postman to post the router to localhost:3000/api/chatapp/register i am gettig error message
**Cannot POST /api/register**

CODE:

**server.js**

```js
const express=require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const cookiePaser=require('cookie-parser');
// const logger=require('morgan');

const app=express();

const dbConfig= require('./config/secret');

//adding middleware
app.use(cookiePaser()); //save our token in the cookie
// app.use(logger('dev')); // to display the url and http status code in the console

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(
    dbConfig.url,{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}
    );

const auth=require('./routes/authRoutes');

app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'})); //data coming in from form is limited up to 50 mb size
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit:'50mb'}));
app.use('/api/chatapp',auth);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Running on port 3000');
})
```

**authRoute.js**

```js
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();

const AuthCtrl=require('../controllers/auth');

router.post('/register',AuthCtrl.CreateUser);

module.exports=router;
```

**auth.js**

```js
module.exports={
  CreateUser(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
  }
};
```

**userSchema.js**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  password: { type: String },
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

nodemon server and mongod are  running fine

[Postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpIBA.png)

for further details kindly look into my github repo :
https://github.com/Umang01-hash/chatApp-backend

Comment: In the Postman screenshot you have attached, you are sending `POST` request to `http:localhost:3000/api/register` instead of `http:localhost:3000/api/chatapp/register`

Comment: Thankyou that solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure if that's the correct endpoint? Check out the folder structure and see this image for your answer.[image]

Comment: Prakash Timalsina i have used app.use('/api/chatapp',auth) so my endpoint will be like :
localhost:3000/api/chatapp/login

Comment: https://github.com/Umang01-hash/chatApp-backend
please look at my repo to find out more